Getting the device name on the local network
In my C# program, I need to get the IP address, mac address and device name on the local network. At the same time, it is necessary to display only those devices whose names begin with tasmota (i.e. I need to find the sonoff relay). I can get IP and mac using the arp -a command, there are no problems with this.
But how to get the device name? nbtstat commands do not work, it says “node was not found”. How can I get the device name? What libraries or commands are there?

Not really a C# question if you're looking for (command line) commands.
Try ipconfig /all
returns something like
Windows IP Configuration...Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . :whatyouareafter
and a bunch of other stuff including MAC and IP addresses (for all adapters)

Did you try GetHostEntry?

@KlausGütter, yeah, and it returns System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 'No such host is known'

If your network infrastructure does not support reverse lookups, you will have to find some other way to identify the Sonoff relay.

Short answer: System.Net.Dns.GetHostByAddress()
Longer answer: Where do the names come from in the first place? They aren't inherently part of a network's operation; you should know whether you're dealing with NetBIOS names, mDNS names, names the devices report via DHCP leases (which then become DNS names with help of your router). Some mechanisms support reverse lookups, others do not.
For example, if the device reports its hostname to the router as part of getting a DHCP lease (very common), and the router then provides local DNS service, and the router is smart enough to also provide reverse lookups, then you can use getnameinfo() or the older gethostbyaddr() – I believe the C#.NET equivalent is System.Net.Dns.GetHostByAddress() – to perform a "reverse DNS" lookup. Not all routers implement that fully, though; some only collect the hostnames for display in their own web UI (and of course, the PC might not be using the router for DNS).

thank you for your answer! I have tried Dns.GetHostByAddress() but i got this exception: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 'No such host is known'. IPAddress is correct and i can ping it.

According to Dns.GetHostByAddress documentation: GetHostByAddress is obsoleted for this type, please use GetHostEntry instead.

@Itallmakescents,i think my network infrastructure does not support reverse lookups as KlausGütter said, because GetHostEntry also didn't work

Perhaps. Do you have Network Discovery turned on in Windows?
